# Evaluate Tcl expressions in text file

Tags: tcl

In text file, I have some Tcl expressions like:

```
# DO NOT EDIT!!
# [exec whoami] - [exec date]
# Generated config file
```

Basically, this text file is a part of a config file. I want to read the file in and replace those expressions with actual values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `subst` command is designed for this purpose.

```
set f [open $theFileName]
set unsubstituted [read $f]
close $f

set substituted [subst $unsubstituted]

# Now use the contents...
```

Be aware that this can change all sorts of things inside your script, as `set` is one of the commands that might be there! To limit the potential damage a bit, run in a sub-interpreter:

```
set f [open $theFileName]
set unsubstituted [read $f]
close $f

set i [interp create]
set substituted [interp eval $i [list subst $unsubstituted]]
interp delete $i
```

The script will still be able to `exit` (or `exec rm -rf *`; it's genuinely as unsafe as running an arbitrary program) but at least won't be able to change your internal configuration unexpectedly.

---

The info that `whoami` produces is available directly in Tcl as `$tcl_platform(user)`.

The info that `exec date` produces is available directly in Tcl as `clock format [clock seconds]`. Well, with slightly different field order for me by default it seems…

Comment: This is great. I only need to read the file as a string and replace part of it and collect the template files into a single file, so I won't need to create a separate interpreter. Thanks for you advice though.